# Common elements between two differents lists (a list and a list of lists of dictionaries) with no duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

i need help to get common elements between two lists. One list is a list of strings, the other one is a list of list of dictionaries.
E.g. :

```
Mylist1 =
[
[{"ABC":"POS"},{"ELEMENT":"Hair"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"POS"},{"ELEMENT":"Salmon"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"BREV"},{"ABC":"XUA"},{"ELEMENT":"Salmon"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"NUON"},{"ELEMENT":"Magic"},{"ELEMENT":"Question"},{"ELEMENT":"Hair"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"NUON"},{"ELEMENT":"Romance"},{"ELEMENT":"Noun"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"NUON"},{"ELEMENT":"Magic"},{"ELEMENT":"Question"},{"ELEMENT":"Hair"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"NUON"},{"ELEMENT":"Romance"},{"ELEMENT":"Noun"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}]
]

Mylist2 =
["XUA","Salmon","Bride","Brother","House"]
```

How can i check if the strings in Mylist2 are contained in MyList1's value and get the index that corresponds to the longest common element?
E.g:
In my example with Mylist1 and Mylist2 i want to get the 3nd element:

```
[{"ABC":"BREV"},{"ABC":"XUA"},{"ELEMENT":"Salmon"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}]
```

How should i procede to do it? Can someone give me directions on how to do it?

Edit: The two list are generated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
Mylist1 = [
[{"ABC":"POS"},{"ELEMENT":"Hair"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"POS"},{"ELEMENT":"Salmon"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"BREV"},{"ABC":"XUA"},{"ELEMENT":"Salmon"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"NUON"},{"ELEMENT":"Magic"},{"ELEMENT":"Question"},{"ELEMENT":"Hair"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"NUON"},{"ELEMENT":"Romance"},{"ELEMENT":"Noun"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"NUON"},{"ELEMENT":"Magic"},{"ELEMENT":"Question"},{"ELEMENT":"Hair"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}],
[{"ABC":"NUON"},{"ELEMENT":"Romance"},{"ELEMENT":"Noun"},{"ELEMENT":"Bride"},{"ELEMENT":"Brother"},{"ELEMENT":"House"},{"ELEMENT":"Fish"}]
]

Mylist2 = ["XUA","Salmon","Bride","Brother","House"]
MySet2 = set(Mylist2)

# `a` is an element of Mylist1, i.e. a list of dictionaries
# `b` is an element of `a`, i.e. a dictionary with a single key-value pair
# `b.values()` contains that value, and `list(b.values()[0])` is the value itself
# `set(list(b.values())[0] for b in a)` is the set of all such values in `a`
# `... & MySet2` keeps only the elements of the set that are also present in MySet2
counts = [len(set(list(b.values())[0] for b in a) & MySet2) for a in Mylist1]
print(counts)

# Now just find the max count
best = 0
for i in range(len(Mylist1)):
    if counts[i] > counts[best]:
        best = i

print(Mylist1[best])
```

Answer (score 1):

What I can comprehend is that you want all dictionaries from Mylist1 whose keys are present in Mylist2, right?

Not sure if you wanted to do this, but here's the code:

```
final_list_of_dicts = []
for each_list in Mylist1:
    for each_dict in each_list:
        for key,value in each_dict.items():
            # if key in Mylist2 or value in Mylist2:
            if value in Mylist2:
                final_list_of_dicts.append(each_dict)
final_list_of_dicts
```

Output :

```
[{'ELEMENT': 'Bride'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Brother'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'House'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Salmon'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Bride'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Brother'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'House'},
 {'ABC': 'XUA'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Salmon'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Bride'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Brother'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'House'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Bride'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Brother'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'House'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Bride'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Brother'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'House'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Bride'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Brother'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'House'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Bride'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Brother'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'House'}]
```

Also for unique :

```
from ast import literal_eval


unique_dicts = [literal_eval(each_string) for each_string in list(set([str(each_dict) for each_dict in final_list_of_dicts] ))]
unique_dicts
```

Out :

```
[{'ELEMENT': 'House'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Brother'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Salmon'},
 {'ABC': 'XUA'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Bride'}]
```

I believe you can change these to your requirements :) Good Luck Mate! GodSpeed!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does the job?

Why is it so difficult?

```
Mylist1[2]
```

Output :

```
[{'ABC': 'BREV'},
 {'ABC': 'XUA'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Salmon'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Bride'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Brother'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'House'},
 {'ELEMENT': 'Fish'}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I edited my question, the two list are generated randomly, so i cannot use your answer. Your answer is correct by it only applies to this specific list and not all list possibly generated.

Comment: Can you provide other sample cases?

Comment: It does not exactly make sense to me how the dicts change!